# WPF: Single TreeViewItem bold

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am new to Xaml and somehow i got stuck here. I googled a lot of different approaches but neither did work :-( I hope someone has here has an idea and can help me :-)

With the help of a few tutorials in the internet I got this TreeView. It works like a charme :-)

```
<TreeView>                    
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Number}">                    
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"  Source="image.ico"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.ID}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.Number.Count}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ItemID}">
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding ItemInfo}">
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"  Source="image.ico"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Items"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemInfo.Count}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Number}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding SetInfo}">
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"  Source="image.ico"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Sets"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetInfo.Count}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.ID}"/>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding GroupInfo}">
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"  Source="image.ico"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Groups"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupInfo.Count}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Number}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem>                    
</TreeView>
```

The problem is now that I want the selected item (with mouse click) gets bold. But only the selected item (not items below or above). It doesnt matter on which level the item is.

I tried this a lot of variations but none did work. This two were the best ones but they always select a hole node or just the top node and I couldnt break it down for one single node.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

---

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Comment: You mean a single `TreeViewItem` with Items+Sets+Groups, or only the header of the `TreeViewItem` (ItemID)?

Comment: Hey, if I select a item I want the item bold. If I select the header of a Set or a Group I want only the header bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this `Style`?

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Hey, nah this didnt work either. Everthing I try (with the "IsSelected" and "Bold") works just on the top node.

Comment: Select I this top node item `<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Number}">` the whole Tree gets bold but I nothing happens on the other levels or itmes

Comment: Strange! I’d tested above style and it worked for me. Are you setting any other style or templates?

Comment: No I have just the plain TreeView code like I posted it above. I wrapped your code into `<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>` and put it after the `<TreeView>` line. But only thing I can do is to select the first node. Nothing happens when I Click die other nodes or items. Is it because I have `<TreeViewItem...>` (Line 2) and other `<TreeViewItem...>` (Line 14, 30, 47) in the first one?

Comment: Don't set it as `ItemContainerStyle`. Just include above `Style` inside your `TreeView` resources, it should work. Updated the above answer with this detail.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub kindly consider upvoting if the answer really added value. Thanks!